# How can I make Twitter Bootstrap modal animation faster?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I really like the Twitter Bootstrap modal, but showing it with the animation is a bit slow. I'd say around 500ms.

Is there a way to make it faster? I looked in `bootstrap-modal.js` but couldn't find anything compelling that could help.

And, I don't want to deactivate the animation completely because I've found out that it's a good trick to make response times seem faster in the eyes of the user ;o)

Comment: Good question. In my case, the SPA I'm building makes extensive use of modals.. and their associated events `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () { .... }` to trigger other logic. When it comes time to unit test this stuff, I'd like to speed up the execution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can manipulate the `.fade` class as explained here:
[How can I change the speed of the fade for alert messages in Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441281/how-can-i-change-the-speed-of-the-fade-for-alert-messages-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: Modifying .fade class based on that link answer is only for adjusting the background fading speed. The slide down and slide up speed seems to be unchanged.

Comment: Except, if you remove the `fade` class entirely, then there is also no sliding animation done.

Comment: As @Aryo pointed out, modifying `.fade` will not affect the modal slide animation. There is another thread that shows how to solve this problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Slide animation can be changed by modifying `.modal.fade .modal-dialog` in bootstrap.css as suggested here: [Modify Bootstrap Modal Transition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29145881/10887376)

Quite late to the party, however this question is the first search result in google, and question hasn't really been answered. So, I thought this might help someone. Cheers!