# How to adjust the delay of the opening of a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using `gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 2.3.0.0"`, which means that I am using `Bootstrap 2`. The modal is documented [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals).

My own modal starts like this:

```
#Modal.modal.hide.fade{"aria-hidden" => "true", "aria-labelledby" => "jobsModalLabel", :role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}
```

I open my modal like this:

```
$("#Modal").modal().css "margin-left": ->
        -($(@).width() / 2)
```

I would like to have it load faster, but I can't read from the documentation how to control the delay time. I have tried to remove the `.fade` class from my modal, but that speeds to loading up too much. So I need to keep the fade functionality, but just make it faster.

Not sure if this is a js or css problem. I suppose it can be solved both ways, but I don't know how.

When I overwrite my `.fade` class with the below, my fading does not speed up:

```
.fade {
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.01s linear;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.01s linear;
       -ms-transition: opacity 0.01s linear;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.01s linear;
           transition: opacity 0.01s linear;
}
```

If I increased to e.g. `3.00s`, it slows down though...

It seems like `.fade` has to do with the process of adding backdrop. I wish to speed up the process of the modal traveling from the top of the screen to its final position. This process happens after the backdrop is added.

Comment: You can manipulate the .fade class as explained here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441281/how-can-i-change-the-speed-of-the-fade-for-alert-messages-in-twitter-bootstrap][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441281/how-can-i-change-the-speed-of-the-fade-for-alert-messages-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, but my problem has to do with the "second part" of the modal creation. Check out my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bootstrap v3 (I happen to be on v3.4.1), you can edit `modal.js` (or if you have an aggregated `bootstrap.js`, you can find the modal section marked by a `// MODAL CLASS DEFINITION` header) to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Change 
`Modal.TRANSITION_DURATION` and `Modal.BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION` to something really low, like 0 or 1 --

```
  ...
  Modal.TRANSITION_DURATION = 1
  Modal.BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION = 1
  ...
```

Then the transitions will occur as instantaneously as possible.

Here's a link to the source code I'm referring to -- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.4.1/js/modal.js#L39